# MySql connection in differenct class C#

Tags: c#, mysql

Okey, so I am new to C# and I have tried to move my Mysql connection string to another class but I can't seem to open the connection once I call the method and I really can't see what's wrong.

So this is the connection method in a new class(DatabaseC)

```
public static void Connection()
    {
        try
        {
            ConnectionStringSettings conSettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cs"];
            string conn = conSettings.ConnectionString;
            MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection(conn);
            connect.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

And here I call the method in a Form

```
private bool validate_login(string u, string p)
    {
        DatabaseC.Connection();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM account WHERE Password COLLATE latin1_general_cs = @password AND User COLLATE latin1_general_cs = @username";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", u);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", p);
        MySqlDataReader login = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    }
```

Sorry for if the code looks bad but as I said im new.

Comment: yikes don't store the users password in plain text!

Comment: So glad a beginner knows about parameterized sql

Comment: @DanielA.White if its on the server side then who cares

Comment: @DanielA.White you do know that your password is sent in plain text over http right?

Comment: @Steve yep.... thats why we have https.

Comment: @DanielA.White if I remember right https doesn't encrypt the password either. All it does is to make sure the two parties talking to each other are indeed the ones expected. And on top of that the server is going to use a string variable to retrieve the password so its plain text in the beginning anywayz

Comment: @Steve no https is for encrypting the whole request/response path. the certs provide the expected party part of the equation.

Comment: @DanielA.White regardless of https, server controller method for login probably looks like this public bool Login(string username, string password). And I don't think there is a way around that. If we have already did it in the beginning why bother to do it differently after.

Comment: ya hash your passwords. It's a no-brainer

Comment: Get bouncycastle or something. One verifies the hash with a yay or nay. One does not compare a cleartext password in a `where` clause, and one does not compare a hash in a where clause. Otherwise you are doing it wrong and are subject to Timing attacks at best (and worse more likely)

Comment: I have not learned to encrypt/decrypt yet and this program is only for learning. All tho I'll look into it right now

Comment: @DanielA.White ohhhhhh you are talking about storing it in plain text. I thought you mean storing it in plain text in memory with a variable. In that case im totally with you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should return the instance of the MySqlConnection opened

```
public static MySqlConnection Connection()
{
    ConnectionStringSettings conSettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cs"];
    string conn = conSettings.ConnectionString;
    MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection(conn);
    connect.Open();
    return connect;
}
```

Now you can change your calling code to receive the connection and use it

```
private bool validate_login(string u, string p)
{
    using(MySqlConnection cnn = DatabaseC.Connection())
    using(MySqlCommand cmd = cnn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "......"
        ...
        using(MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
           .....
        }  // Here the reader is closed and destroyed
    } // Here the connection closed and destroyed with the command 
}
```

Notice that a connection is a disposable object and thus you should be sure to destroy it once you have finished to use it. This is the work of the using statement.

Another problem fixed with this code is the fact that a command needs to know the connection to use, your actual code doesn't link the command with the connection and thus it cannot work.

EDIT: you comment below should be added to the answer. The Try/Catch in the Connection method should be removed. You do nothing there and catching the exception creates only complications in the calling code that need to handle a null return value. It is better to let the exception bubble up until there is a method that has something to do with that (like logging it for example)

Comment: Thanks Steve! this solution worked great. But what about the other return value that is needed outside try-catch? should I just make it null?

Comment: Uhm, no, you do nothing in that exception, it is better to remove the try/catch and let the caller handle it

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need to open the connection where you are using the connection, try this way

```
public static MySqlConnection Connection()
    {
        try
        {
            ConnectionStringSettings conSettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cs"];
            string conn = conSettings.ConnectionString;
            MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection(conn);
            return connect;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

then

```
private bool validate_login(string u, string p)
    {
        DatabaseC.Connection().Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM account WHERE Password COLLATE latin1_general_cs = @password AND User COLLATE latin1_general_cs = @username";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", u);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", p);
        MySqlDataReader login = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: you forgot about using and connection variable